# Put multi elements into a column in PanelGrid columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**I don't want to use the row & column tags**

A | B | C | D | E

```
<p:panelGrid columns = "5">
    <h:outputText value="A"/>
    <h:outputText value="B"/>
    <h:outputText value="C"/>
    <h:outputText value="D"/>
    <h:outputText value="E"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

If I wanna put B & C into a same column like this:

A | BC | D | E

the only way is using row and column tags?

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="A"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="B"/>
            <h:outputText value="C"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="D"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="E"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Is there any tag can grouping the B&C?

because I want the p:panelGrid responsive 
but p:row & p:column not support

Thanks

Comment: Use h:panelGroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `h:panelGroup` like

```
<p:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:outputText value="A" />
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="B" />
        <h:outputText value="C" />
    <h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="D" />
    <h:outputText value="E" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I bet you can find an exact or very close 'duplicate' in stackoverflow. Please check and mark this question as such.